Distinguish between forms on the same page in 'Form responses'?
I have a page with two forms. The forms are created using the Jetpack 'Form' block.
The responses show up in the backend, under 'Feedback'. The list on this page includes the 'Source', which is the relative URL of the page that contains the forms.
For both forms, this is the same, as they are on the same page. So, by looking at the 'Source', I can not determine what form was filled in.
Is there a way to change this, so that the 'Source' does identify the form? For example, I could image the source to be something like '/contact-us/#form-1' and '/contact-us/#form-2'.

If possible, you could try adding a hidden field with the form name (eg, <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="my-form-1" />). I don't know if that's possible with Jetpack Forms; you'll need to check with their support team about this.

Thanks @PatJ. I was thinking of that too, but I didn't see a hidden field as being available. Alternatively, I also considered a dropdown with only one value, but I don't seem to be able to set that one value as the default value, meaning the user still has to select that value. I can make that field obligatory, but that still requires more input from the user than I would like to require.
